# Get the AxesImage instance within AxesSubplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to get a pointer to an `AxesImage` instance within a subplot? For example, in a general case such as:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.imshow(data)
```

Getting back the `AxesImage` object via something like `ax.get_image`. At the moment I do this via:

```py
ls = [type(x) for x in ax.get_children()]
img = ax.get_children()[ls.index(matplotlib.image.AxesImage)]
```

And was wondering if there is a less explicit way of doing it.

Comment: Do you mean other than `im=ax.imshow(data)`? `imshow` returns an `AxesImage`

Comment: I know. I mean how to get the AxesImage instance from ax once you have already called an ax.imshow (i.e. the AxesImage is within the ax).

Comment: Maybe this? https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_images.html

Comment: Nice one. I did not know it existed.

Comment: Neither did I! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg) in the comments, there is a method to get a list of Images within an AxesSubpolot like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.imshow(data)

img = ax.get_images()[0] # only one image in this axes instance.
```